# Setting up port 3360 access on McAfee firewall using windows 7 for network access

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

I have a windows 7 machine serving me PHP / mySQL etc i have set is all up well and is all working on local machine as well as on local network machines.

My issue is that when i try to connect workbench / sequel Pro to this machine's database i get an error.  I worked out it has something to do with the firewall as turing the firewall off i can connect via the local network machines and their workbench / sequel Pro programmes.

I am using or currently using McAfee Firewall and within the port settings there is no preset for port 3360. SO i tried to set one up and still nothing.

Am i missing anything or would i need to do some more work for it to connect.

Machine running the PHP is Windows 7 using McAfee Firewall.
local network machines are a mixture of Windows and Macs.

Shall i drop McAfee and use the standard Windows 7 firewall if that would be easier?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mcafee+firewall+mysql

Comment: Thanks for the google link, something i have tried several times before the post :-), and still no luck hence the option to ask more knowledgable people.

Comment: see my answer below, sometimes my wife is correct.

Answer (score 0):

its actually in th etxt above but for the love of me i kept typing it in.

```
  its PORT 3306
```

Not 3360.